# Where can I find a very concise list of the html tags that should not be used

Tags: html, css, xhtml, cross-browser

Reasons that the tags would no longer be used could include...

- deprecated
- limited browser compatibility
- Best Practices (using another tag +css to perform the same function)

Comment: Bonus if there is a nicely formatted 1 page reference I can print out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Start by looking here: http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html

2) Then, there is tag list with DTD support here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp (yes, I know it's W3Schools).

Answer (score 2):

[Deprecated  Tags](http://fantasai.tripod.com/qref/HTML4/deprecated.html) and  [Deprecated  Tags that are in widespread Use](http://css-tricks.com/list-of-depreciated-elements-still-in-widespread-use/) should get you started.

[CSS Support by Browser](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css) and [CSS Browser support](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2009/02/css-browser-support/) can also help you out with browser based information on CSS tags.

Both feature alternatives to the depreciated tags, and list those that are currently no longer used that lack an alternative form.

Comment: I'm not sure how much I should trust a site hosted by TRIPOD!